# "Совместить" указатель и ссылку в аргументе функции

Tags: c++

Есть две функции:

```
template<class T>
void Foo_ref(T &x) { x.some_method(); }

template<class T>
void Foo_ptr(T *x) { x->some_method(); }
```

В полном коде функции намного больше. Но суть именно такая - в одной аргумент используется как указатель, в другой как ссылка, в остальном код идентичен. Хочется устранить дублирование кода, оставив только одну функцию, при этом чтобы вызовы остались теми же (вариант сделать вместо вызовов `Foo(x_ref)` и `Foo(x_ptr)` вызовы `Foo(x_ref)` и `Foo(*x_ptr)` не хочется использовать).

Один из способов - сделать класс-враппер, который инициализируется по ссылке или указателю, а внутри одинаковым интерфейсом пробрасывает вызовы всех функций на содержимое. Что-то вроде такого:

```
template<class T>
class wrapper_ptr_ref
{
    T *x;
public:
    wrapper_ptr_ref(T &i_x) : x(&i_x) {}
    wrapper_ptr_ref(T *i_x) : x( i_x) {}
    T& operator T ()
    {
        return *x;
    }
}

template<class T>
void Foo_ptr(wrapper_ptr_ref<T> x) { x.some_method(); }
```

Но может в stl уже есть что-то подобное ? То есть хочется враппер, который объединяет интерфейс ссылки и указателя.

Comment: вообще это немного странно: указатель, в отличие от ссылки, может быть nullptr - и это должно быть обработано отдельно, так что код полностью идентичным вряд ли может быть. Но, если после проверки указателя он просто разыменовывается и логика в остальном такая же как и со ссылкой - то почему бы просто не передать разыменованный указатель в функцию которая принимает ссылку?

Comment: просто напишите частичную специализацию функции для указателей и возвращайте определенную функцию, передав ему разыменованный указатель. Тут не нужны никакие повторения кода _ просто вызов той же функции с соответствующим аргументом.

Comment: Если делать враппер, то перестает работать автоматический вывод шаблонного параметра. Я бы использовал `template<class T> void Foo(T &&x)`, и сделал бы функцию, которая ссылки возвращает без изменений, а указатели возвращает разыменованными.